# JMeter: Count comparison of value fetched from Beanshell Postprocessor, using the Beanshell assertion

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

I have a JMeter Test which sends a GET request to fetch certain filenames.
I was trying to get the count of the number of files and compare it with an integer value.
If the count is greater than the integer, the test should pass.

For this, I used a Beanshell PostProcessor to get the count of the string obtained in the response.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;

String response = new String(data);
int count = StringUtils.countMatches(response, ".xml");
```

However, was hoping to use this count value in the Beanshell assertion to validate it with a number. What is the right way of doing this?
I am newbie to JMeter. Please Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do everything in a single assertion. Be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so I would suggest going for [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) instead.

Example code

```
String response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
int count = StringUtils.countMatches(response, ".xml");

int expectedCount = 10; //change it to your own expected value

if (count != expectedCount) {
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage("Expected count to be " + expectedCount + ", actually got: " + count);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri T . Seeing some errors in this case. If I were to use JSR223, could you please advise as to what steps are to be performed for the above mentioned issue? Would just a JSR223 Assertion suffice? How should I extract the count of the strings from the Response Text?

Comment: You still need to add `import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;` line to the beginning of the script. I'm not telepathic enough to guess what other "some errors" you could have

Comment: Yes. I have added that line. However, I see the following error:`Attempt to resolve method: setFailure() on undefined variable or class name: AssertionResult` .

Comment: Are you sure you're using this code in the **JSR223 Assertion**?

Comment: No. I am currently using Beanshell Assertion. Have enclosed the code within the try catch block as well. But encountering the above mentioned error. @DmitriT

Comment: Beanshell Assertion doesn't have `AssertionResult` shorthand, if you **need** to use beanshell you need to use `SampleResult` instead of `prev`,  `Failure = true` instead of `AssertionResult.setFailure(true)` and `FailureMessage = "Expected count to be " + expectedCount + ", actually got: " + count` instead of `AssertionResult.setFailureMessage`. However I would [strongly recommend using JSR223 Assertion with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead/)

Comment: Thank you! That solved it.